# Hotmail and yahoo html newsletter mail issue

Tags: php, html, css

I want to send a  html newsletter to various users using php,html.
Below is the separate code for yahoo and hotmail.
I am using separate code because I am getting a layout issue.

The code for yahoo users:

```
<table border="0" style="width:248px;float:left;margin:15px 15px 0px 0px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="img_tbl"> 
<img style="border:0;display:block;"  src="" align="top"  />
```

The code for Hotmail users:

```
<table border="0" style="width:248px;float:left;margin:15px 15px 0px 0px;display:inline-block;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="img_tbl">
<img style="border:0;display:block;"  src="" align="top"  />
```

When I am forwarding the same mail from yahoo to hotmail the layout and images breaks.
Because code is different for yahoo.

Comment: Hotmail strips out a lot of things from your CSS. You should make your design more robust (and uglier basically).

Comment: Don't tables "float left" by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML and CSS in email design is a pain, basically - every email client renders differently, with Outlook in particular being frustrating due to using Word as its rendering engine.

Campaign Monitor post a very useful summary of all the CSS that will or won't work in which of the email clients: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/